# Always get "Authorization has been denied for this request." using Bearer tokens in Identity 2?

Tags: c#, authorization, asp.net-identity-2, bearer-token

Using postman I can request a token, here it is:

```
{
    "access_token": "N1FL606bmDkZyLplpkLAihaviMQhB042z-rhY262M_W5nSWIv8fDOQiYkEn6GCuDnrxpdOWBS7lpxlBazHYlwnP1RvpDFED1i_ml89QNspyGOWB6TcMkT1MmfUAZ617k9MNvl5UJh2jKzUwvDDeXMURG9tEtmE3UX2L2D-1VA9kqYOzOB1UYbpMAfdTi84jsbR0lhLkNkReQ5fqg4B3IFbbWNGWu5ONb1uuf00ixL-BIMqSvEaNn58_zCyAVFWVzcH2tayYTGT5p_AItKfYiWaYHKC0pDoZ_OBdlpB7Odc7ScwjwFM5vtpBZE81rpk8yjXnrTEk_j9n0eiloJnpWwA",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 899,
    "refresh_token": "60da311d10f043b892c703c7fb7ab061",
    "as:client_id": "Erp",
    "userName": "bbauer",
    ".issued": "Tue, 30 Jun 2015 17:56:10 GMT",
    ".expires": "Tue, 30 Jun 2015 18:11:10 GMT"
}
```

I can also get information from an unprotected resource like so:
http://localhost:60689/api/Accounts/User/bbauer

```
{
    "url": "http://localhost:60689/api/accounts/user/31",
    "id": 31,
    "userName": "bbauer",
    "fullName": "Brian Bauer",
    "email": null,
    "emailConfirmed": false,
    "roles": [
        "Administrator"
    ],
    "claims": []
}
```

From that I see that the user is in the "Administrator" role. When I try to get a protected resource, I ALWAYS get this back: ***"Authorization has been denied for this request."***

Here is the method in the controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
[Route("user/{id:int}", Name = "GetUserById")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUser(int id)
{
    var user = await AppUserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

    if (user != null)
    {
        return Ok(TheModelFactory.Create(user));
    }

    return NotFound();
}
```

Here are my settings in postman:
http://localhost:60689/api/Accounts/User/31
**Content-Type:** application/json
**Accept:** application/json
**Authorization:** Bearer N1FL606bmDkZyLplpkLAihaviMQhB042z-rhY262M_W5nSWIv8fDOQiYkEn6GCuDnrxpdOWBS7lpxlBazHYlwnP1RvpDFED1i_ml89QNspyGOWB6TcMkT1MmfUAZ617k9MNvl5UJh2jKzUwvDDeXMURG9tEtmE3UX2L2D-1VA9kqYOzOB1UYbpMAfdTi84jsbR0lhLkNkReQ5fqg4B3IFbbWNGWu5ONb1uuf00ixL-BIMqSvEaNn58_zCyAVFWVzcH2tayYTGT5p_AItKfYiWaYHKC0pDoZ_OBdlpB7Odc7ScwjwFM5vtpBZE81rpk8yjXnrTEk_j9n0eiloJnpWwA

I can use fiddler to verify the authorization header is being sent. Another thing to note is when I pass the access_token in to get the unprotected /user/username resource, I can break in code and see the ClaimsPrincipal with these settings:
**AuthenticationType:** Bearer
**IsAuthenticated:** true
**Name:** bbauer

However, if I test User.IsInRole("Administrator") its always false. Why is it false? The AspNetUserRole table has the entry, and when I fetch the user I see his one role of "Administrator"... what on God's green earth am I missing here?

Here is my Startup class if that helps:

```
public class Startup
{
    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions { get; private set; }
    public static OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions OAuthBearerOptions { get; private set; }
    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();

        ConfigureOAuth(app);

        WebApiConfig.Register(httpConfig);

        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(httpConfig);
    }

    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);

        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(PublicClientId),
            RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider(),
        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);

        OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I needed to add roles to my ClaimsIdentity in my SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider's GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method. Here is the code (see commented section):

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    var allowedOrigin = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin") ?? "*";

    context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });

    var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

    ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

    if (user == null)
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
        return;
    }

    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));

    //this loop is where the roles are added as claims
    foreach (var role in userManager.GetRoles(user.Id))
    {
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
    }

    var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {
            "as:client_id", context.ClientId ?? string.Empty
        },
        {
            "userName", context.UserName
        }
    });

    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
    context.Validated(ticket);
}
```